# Django - Overriding save method to send data

Tags: python, django

I'm working on human management system where a user applies for leave and the respected data should get into the history table only when the `status == '0'`

I've tried with signals but every time when admin saves, it's getting registered into the table. I've read that, it's better to override `save()` rather use signals

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (('0', 'Rejected'),('1', 'Accepted'),)

class Employee(models.Model):

    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = STATUS_CHOICES)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if Leave.status == '1':
            history = History()
            history.employee_ID = self.employee_ID
            history.name = self.name
            history.save()
            print('data sent')

class History(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

What's the mistake I've been doing while overriding the `save` method?

Comment: Why do you make a *new* `Employee` here? I think you probably want to use `self` instead of `leave` in the `.save()` function. But regardless: nor `.save()` and signals are actually robusts way to handle it: these can be bypassed rather easily.

Comment: You also did not override the `.save()` function, but defined a new one: `save_data`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my bad, check it now.

Comment: Well like said before, why do you construct a new `Employee` object? Furthermore yo did not call the `super().save()` function, so the employee is not saved, and you use another (new) employee to do checking.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you please give me an answer below, I didn't get you though. I'm very much new to django.

Comment: I think the `if Leave.status == '1':` is still incorrect, now you aim to fetch the `status` of a `Leave` model (that might/might not exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the important part `super(Employee, self).save()`

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Employee, self).save()
    if self.status == '0':
        history = History.objects.create(
            employee_ID = self.employee_ID,
            name = self.name,
        )
        print('data sent')
```

Now you will save the model, and if is status is 0 (you have 1 in your code) you will create an history model entry (maybe add a datetime)